# When should I use a hash vs a class

Tags: java, ruby, class, hash, hashmap

I have always used the saying "If it's data storage, use a hash/array, if there are methods involved, use a class", however I might be rethinking that statement.

I have a Hash I'm using to map out parent/children relationships.  This hash is listed below.  It is becoming a very large data set, and while it stores well in a JSON object, it becomes hard to debug if/when something goes wrong, and it gets harder to add or remove information since the data structure is so tightly coupled.

Should I have a class for Test, Feature, and AllTests, where Features is an array of type Feature inside of AllTests, and Tests are an array of type Test attached to Feature?  I feel from a readability & loose coupling standpoint this is the better solution, but I feel I'm adding complexity by using classes instead of a hash map.  Thoughts?

```
{all_tests =>
  {features =>
    {feature_name => ,
     feature_line_number => ,
     test =>
      {test_name => ,
       test_line_num => ,
       test_status => ,
       error_message => }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What complexity is being added? Having a known set of accessors and methods isn't any more complex than wrapping a hash with the same method names so you don't fat-finger a hash key.

Comment: So you don't believe in [Value Objects](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html) I take it. Also, you've tagged this question with two languages but the answer may be different in each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an OO point of view (and you're programming in Java...), you should use classes for that.

I don't think it adds any complexity at all. That's what classes are made for. If those classes don't have any methods but getters and setters, well, that's the place for so called TO's (Transfer Objects). And even while this should not be considered as an design argument, of course it's more debug-friendly than hashes.

Comment: To expand on this, I decided to change our design pattern to include a database.  By changing the pattern to a database ORM, It made the class option a no-brainer